# Mobile HTML5 development: Backbone.js + Zepto vs. Sencha

Tags: android, ios, html, backbone.js, zepto

I am about to start working on my first mobile HTML5 app. It is NOT a graphically challenging app like a game, but a typical mobile app that interacts with a REST server.

I already know Backbone, and zepto is pretty much same as jQuery so I was thinking about using this combination (and packaging it with Phonegap).  But then I saw this video from Sencha https://plus.google.com/+Scobleizer/posts/ZtnZNrCfWv6 and am now amazed.

I used to think I have to pay for a Sencha license but as the video says, the license is free (Although I don't know how they make money if everything is free). Also, they have all the implementations of technically-challenging browsing modules, like carousel and infinite scrolls.

Although I've been using Backbone a lot, I have never done a mobile version (I've never really worried much about re-using cells, etc.), so I am wondering how difficult this part is if I wanted to go with Backbone+zepto option. I can imagine implementing cell recycle myself and feeling unhappy about how unoptimized it is. But then again, it could be easier than I think. I have no idea what it's like.

So please, could you share your experience using Backbone + zepto? Also pros and cons of using either option vs. the other. Thank you!

Comment: I do not see where [Sencha](https://www.sencha.com/store/) would be free. Though I would not say that charging for a framework is bad in any way. However, keep in mind that native code *is* faster, it is only harder to maintain and you need to optimize while HTML/5 uses hardware acceleration in many places. In other words native code has the *potential* to be faster, but it may not be easy to get there.

Comment: Currently Sencha is free: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/. "Is Sencha Touch free-of-charge for commercial use?
Yes, Sencha Touch is free for use under the terms of our commercial license agreement."